# Javascript File not Caching

Tags: javascript, php, caching

Im using the Keenthemes Metronic admin template and having real trouble with 1 file. Its a javascript file and for some reason no matter what i try i cannot get it to cache. Its a static file with a size of 3.5mb so loading this each time is killing the scripts.

I have tried adding bits to me htaccess and to the header but this changes nothing.

Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm ... times have changed, when I was a beginner with HTML and JS, it was said, that "_if your script file is larger than 20 kB, you've done something wrong._" Have you emptied the cache, so that there is enough space to store the JS file?

Comment: i would agree with you but the complexities of modern scripts mean they are bigger, however have to agree that 3.5mb is ridiculous!!! Hence the reason i would really like it to cache!

Comment: How does this relate to PHP? And have you tried to minify the file?

Comment: The main template that this script is used in is PHP so i inlcuded the Tag. I have tried minifying it and this takes it down to around 2mb, still a very large file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could see from the comment section, you have already tried minimising the file, but it is still very large. You can control the cache of your own browser, but cannot control the cache of the browsers your users are using. Therefore you will not be able to enforce caching the file. You will therefore need to thoroughly read the file and divide it into separate files. You will end up having a core file, which will be useful everywhere and which will be needed to be downloaded and you will have some other files, which are specific to some features, like a file for register/login, another for handling separate features, like choosing colors and so on.

You will need to load your core JS file everywhere, but your specific features will be needed at specific places. You will not need login features, for instance, if the user has already logged in, so you will be able to include the JS files for separate features where they are needed and nowhere else.

Also, You might want to lazy load your JS files, so you will initially load the core file and when it has been successfully loaded, separately load the other files. Those features will be unable initially when the page is loaded, so the page will need to somehow handle or prevent attempts from users of using a feature before its script was loaded.

It would not hurt to minify all these separate files either. Possibly RequireJS can help you to handle requirements, but you can implement your own feature to handle requirements as well.